# Scala unexpected stack overflow

Tags: scala, stack-overflow

I've written this basic program in Scala :

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap

object HelloWorld {

  val treasureMap = new HashMap[BigInt, BigInt]

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(fibCache(10))
  }

  def fibCache(n: BigInt): BigInt = {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
      return n
    }
    return treasureMap.getOrElseUpdate(n, fibCache(n - 1) + fibCache(n - 2))
  }
}
```

and I would expect that with really large values, I'd have an OutOfMemoryError or something, but instead I see this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.math.BigInteger.compareMagnitude(Unknown Source)
    at java.math.BigInteger.compareTo(Unknown Source)
    at scala.math.BigInt.compare(BigInt.scala:141)
    at scala.math.BigInt.$less$eq(BigInt.scala:145)
    at scala.math.BigInt.fitsInLong(BigInt.scala:130)
    at scala.math.BigInt.hashCode(BigInt.scala:120)
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.hashFromNumber(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$HashUtils$class.elemHashCode(HashTable.scala:366)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.elemHashCode(HashMap.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.findEntry(HashTable.scala:108)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.findEntry(HashMap.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.get(HashMap.scala:63)
    at scala.collection.mutable.MapLike$class.getOrElseUpdate(MapLike.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:43)
```

Can someone help explain why?  Also, is there a runtime setting I can use to alleviate this?  Will -Xss help?

Comment: Just ran it on my machine (3GB Macbook) with the latest version of scala and it ran as expected.

Comment: What large value did you use?  What was the result?

Comment: 32/64 bit, available physical memory, and the -Xss parameter will all affect the exact point at which which the problem occurs, so don't fret about the actual numbers chosen.  It's enough to know there will be *some* point at which this blows up, depending on your configuration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A StackOverflowError is a variation on the theme of running out of memory, it's just being precise about exactly which memory area has run out.

So yes, `-Xss` **will** help, but there's a better way....

This page has several alternative implementations that you can try: [http://en.literateprograms.org/Fibonacci_numbers_(Scala)](http://en.literateprograms.org/Fibonacci_numbers_%28Scala%29)

You'll want to use the tail-recursive or stream-based variant to keep the stack size down.

Comment: I'm familiar with what a StackOverflow is.  When I write this equivalent in Java, it doesn't SO.  It runs out of memory before blowing the stack.

Comment: @Amir the code emitted by Scala tends to lean on the stack a bit more heavily than Java code.  Especially if you're writing in a more functional style or adding a couple of levels to the stack by using Scala methods that wrap methods from the Java standard lib.  I wouldn't let it worry you.

Comment: How does a tail-recursive implementation keep the stack size down? jvm based languages such as scala, clojure do not do tail call optimization as the jvm doesn't support it.

Comment: @Babu _JVM_ doesn't do tail call optimization. Scala does.

Comment: @Babu, @Daniel - To expand on that a bit more... The Scala compiler will recognise the tail-call and emit bytecode that performs a jump to the start of the method, feel free to verify this with a Java decompiler of your choosing.  No JVM involvement is required.

Comment: To echo @Kevin a few comments back, I've found Scala's collections (2.8 at least) to be very memory intensive.  Normally that's not an issue, but when doing some Project Euler problems awhile back (brute force and ignorance, moi?), I sometimes found nearly an order-of-magnitude difference in the size of the lists I could assemble using normal Java arrays (not java.util.List) over scala.collection.immutable.List.   Seems to me I even found a comment in the Scaladoc stating this might be the case, but now I can't find it...

Comment: @user unknown - Now fixed, looks like SO introduced a new bug with parsing the trailing `)` in that URL